# How to identify to which group a file owner belongs?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

When using Google Drive and Directory API in java, how can we efficiently identify to which group a file owner belongs?

Answer (score 1):

In the scope of the Drive API, we don't provide any methods you can identify which group a user belongs to.